# Document Folder for iOS 8.1 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode

For `iOS 7.0.3 SDK`, I had an document viewing application and I used to place documents under `~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/<GUID>/Documents/` , which were then accessible when I run the app. However, I do not see any such folder `iOS 8.1 SDK`, and I suspect it might be because I downloaded Xcode via web from developer's site. Am i right in suspecting the above might be the reason i do not 8.1/ folder in `Application Support` for `iPhone Simulator`? If yes, is there a way I could add those folders by determining `Simulator GUID` so my app can start accessing the documents again? Or has the Document folder location been moved to somewhere else?

I followed instructions at [Xcode: directory file for simulator Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593064/xcode-directory-file-for-simulator-iphone) and at [iPhone simulator folder not in Application Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919959/iphone-simulator-folder-not-in-application-support) but it does not seem to fix my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find your app's document folder, you can simply put this into your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and you will see the path in your xcode's console window:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSLog(@"Documents Directory: %@", [paths objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use SimPholder application to know current application location.

[image]

### For xcode 6.0 >

#### Download [SimPholder 2.0 a](http://simpholders.com/)

---

### For xcode 5.1 <

#### Download [SimPholders 1.5](http://kfi-apps.com/apps/simpholders/)

Comment: I am facing some problems installing this app on my mac. Let me work it out and see if it satisfies what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in iOS 8 xcode provide core simulators. so you can find document directory folder using below code. you can write code in `appDidFinishLaunching`

```
NSLog(@"app directory : %@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
```